# Is there a way to initialize hash's values lazily?

Tags: ruby, hash, lazy-evaluation

I have a hash like:

```
h = {
  a: '/users/sign_up',
  b: "/user/#{@user.id]}"
}
```

Later I do `h[:b]`.

Hash values are initialized when hash itself is initialized. But I'd want `@user.id` to be invoked every time when `h[:b]` is invoked.

It seems to be not possible to do it with Ruby's hash. But is there some workaround to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lambdas for the values of the hash, and call the lambda when the actual value is needed, e.g.:

```
h = {
  a: ->{'/users/sign_up'},
  b: ->{"/user/#{@user.id}"}
}

h[:b].call
```

Answer (score 2):

```
h = {}
h.default_proc = proc do |hash, key|
  key == :b ? "/user/#{@user.id}" : nil
end
h[:a] #=> nil
h[:b] #=> "/user/<id>"
```